# Display of special characters in a flash movie, ie: Ó

Tags: flash

I've gotta flash movie that refuses to display the character:

Ó

Does anyone out there have an idea why this may be happening?  I know this is a vague question but i really can't explain it any better than that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed the font to get it to show.

From the menu, choose Text->Font Embedding.

If you have already embedded the font, then make sure you picked the set with that special character in it, that character for instance is not under Punctuation.

CRITICAL INFORMATION for you - you can say, "also include these characters" when you do the font embed, to include your character, and it will show.